# Airflow (Google Composer) TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I'm using airflow(Google composer), but experienced some exceptions below

**TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects**

```
Ooops.

                          ____/ (  (    )   )  \___
                         /( (  (  )   _    ))  )   )\
                       ((     (   )(    )  )   (   )  )
                     ((/  ( _(   )   (   _) ) (  () )  )
                    ( (  ( (_)   ((    (   )  .((_ ) .  )_
                   ( (  )    (      (  )    )   ) . ) (   )
                  (  (   (  (   ) (  _  ( _) ).  ) . ) ) ( )
                  ( (  (   ) (  )   (  ))     ) _)(   )  )  )
                 ( (  ( \ ) (    (_  ( ) ( )  )   ) )  )) ( )
                  (  (   (  (   (_ ( ) ( _    )  ) (  )  )   )
                 ( (  ( (  (  )     (_  )  ) )  _)   ) _( ( )
                  ((  (   )(    (     _    )   _) _(_ (  (_ )
                   (_((__(_(__(( ( ( |  ) ) ) )_))__))_)___)
                   ((__)        \\||lll|l||///          \_))
                            (   /(/ (  )  ) )\   )
                          (    ( ( ( | | ) ) )\   )
                           (   /(| / ( )) ) ) )) )
                         (     ( ((((_(|)_)))))     )
                          (      ||\(|(|)|/||     )
                        (        |(||(||)||||        )
                          (     //|/l|||)|\\ \     )
                        (/ / //  /|//||||\\  \ \  \ _)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node: d93e048dc08a
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 258, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/www/utils.py", line 290, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/www/utils.py", line 337, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/www/views.py", line 1335, in clear
    include_upstream=upstream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1243, in sub_dag
    for t in regex_match + also_include}
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1243, in <dictcomp>
    for t in regex_match + also_include}
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 678, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

What I have tried?

1. From airflow UI interface to clear task, the task, **not work**
2. From command like use command backfill, **not work**
3. Restart Airflow webservice, **not work**
4. Changed DAG retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=5)

Can anyone help with the above? Thanks a lot

I was noticed there have some similar questions on StackOverflow, but those questions not really get the fix.

[Airflow can't pickle _thread._local objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383690/airflow-cant-pickle-thread-local-objects)

[Airflow 1.9.0 ExternalTaskSensor retry_delay=30 yields TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933382/airflow-1-9-0-externaltasksensor-retry-delay-30-yields-typeerror-cant-pickle)

Comment: What is your Cloud Composer image version? Do you use custom operator in the DAG?

Comment: Image version is composer-1.11.2-airflow-1.10.9 . No, I didn't custom operators

Comment: I experienced a similar issue, and in my case I isolated the problem to a SubDag that depended on other SubDags in a complex relationship. Reworking the DAG dependency graph to be a bit simpler caused the issue to go away. I'm not confident enough of this explanation to make it an answer, but if somebody is stuck on this problem, changing your dependency graph to be simpler might at least be worth looking into. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the similar problem was reported on Apache Jira [tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-351), looking into the discussion threads there, I can point out some concerns that might help to overcome this issue:

- I would advise to look through the particular DAG, inspecting the
  correct type of the default arguments for dedicated DAG operator,
  despite the fact that `retry_delay` has been already checked, it
  would worth to review the rest of the parameters, the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933382/airflow-1-9-0-externaltasksensor-retry-delay-30-yields-typeerror-cant-pickle) was
  already mentioned in the question;
- To further debug, verify whether you DAG Operator consumes only
  *pickable*(serializable) object, as per comment being posted [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-351?focusedCommentId=16640103&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16640103).
- I assume that we are still receiving some issues from the users with
  clearing Airflow DAG tasks via Airflow WEB UI, just check out this
  [thread](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8541). In order to
  mitigate this problem you can either delete the failing task within
  Airflow [command-line tool](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref) (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130975/how-to-clear-failing-dags-using-the-cli-in-airflow)) or as a last resort
  remove the `task_id` record from Airflow metadata database.

  Connecting to the one of Composer's workers:

  ```
  kubectl -it exec $(kubectl get po -l run=airflow-worker -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}' \
      -n $(kubectl get ns| grep composer*| awk '{print $1}')) -n $(kubectl get ns| grep composer*| awk '{print $1}') \
      -c airflow-worker -- mysql -u root -h airflow-sqlproxy-service.default
  ```

  Using `mysql` client:

  ```
  mysql> show databases;
  +-----------------------------------------+
  | Database                                |
  +-----------------------------------------+
  | information_schema                      |
  | composer-1-11-3-airflow-1-10-6-* |
  | mysql                                   |
  | performance_schema                      |
  | sys                                     |
  +-----------------------------------------+
  5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
  ```

  Launch connection to `composer-1-11-3-airflow-1-10-6-*` schema:

  `mysql> use composer-1-11-3-airflow-1-10-6-*;`

  Delete the failing `task_id`:

  ```
  delete from task_instance where task_id='<task_id>' AND execution_date='<execution_date>'
  ```